# How to declare an array of matchers

Tags: c++, googlemock

I want to check a vector of strings against a long sequence of matchers. For short sequences I can do:

```
std::vector<std::string> results = SomeCall();
ExpectThat (results, ElementsAre(IsDelay(7), "read", IsDelay(5), "write"));
```

(where `IsDelay` is my own custom matcher).

But `ElementsAre` only works up to 10 elements. If I want to check longer sequences, I could use `ElementsAreArray`, but what do I declare the expected array as? So for example, if I try to do:

```
XXX expected[] = {IsDelay(7), "read", IsDelay(5), "write")};
ExpectThat (results, ElementsAreArray (expected));
```

what should XXX be?

I am using gcc 4.8.1 in C++11 mode, with gmock 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type should be `::testing::Matcher<std::string>`, so:

```
::testing::Matcher<std::string> expected[] = {IsDelay(7), "read",
                                              IsDelay(5), "write"};
```

See the [Matching Containers](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Matching_Containers) section in the docs, specifically the example:

> ```
> // Or, an array of element matchers.
> Matcher<int> expected_vector2 = { 1, Gt(2), _, 3, ... };
> EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo(ElementsAreArray(expected_vector2)));
> ```